# Analogy between list_view_SelectedIndexChanged and list_box_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a handler for list_box:

```
private void list_answers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list_answers.Text == "Question №" + (i + 1))
                {
                    this.ShowOnePanel(i);
                    iter = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

and for list_view:

```
private void list_answers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list_answers.Items[i].Text == "Question №" + (i + 1))
                {
                    this.ShowOnePanel(i);
                    iter = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

It works for listbox, but doesn't work for listview. Why?
P.S. `ShowOnePanel` is my method, that shows one of the panels with question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list_answers.Items[i].Text == "Питання №" + (i + 1))
```

I guess it's `"question"` not `"Питання"`

**EDIT**

```
private void list_answers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list_answers.Items[i].Selected == true) // find selected item

                {
                    if (list_answers.Items[i].Text == "Question №" + (i + 1)) // check it's content
                    this.ShowOnePanel(i);
                    iter = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: No, it's not. I just mistyped. It's not the problem

Comment: it doesn't cause any error. But it doesn't work correctly. In case of listbox, it works in the way I need. In case of listview, this handler doesn't work and cause the program not to work correctly